Enumerate reduced graphs with circuit rank $r$
We say a graph is reduced if it does not have any leaves, and cannot apply smoothing to any vertex.
How many reduced graph are there with circuit rank $r$?
Basically, I'm trying to find graphs with circuit rank $r$ that none are topologically equivalent to each other.
